# How can I fix my "MemoryError: StackOverflow"?

Tags: python, recursion

Can I shorten or otherwise change my program to get rid of the error?

```
#This is Where Everything about the Player is stored
class Player_Data:
    def Player_Data_Vars(self):
        import sys
        #print(sys.getrecursionlimit())
        sys.setrecursionlimit()
        #print(sys.getrecursionlimit())
        def Xp(self):

            Level = 0
        Xp = 0
        Xp = Xp + 10
        if Xp == 10:
            Xp = 0
            Level = Level + 1
            if Xp == 0:
                Hp(self)
        return
        def Hp(self):
            Level = Xp('Level')
            Base_Hp = 100
            Level_Up_Hp = + 20 * Level
            Base_Hp = Base_Hp + Level_Up_Hp
            print(Base_Hp)
            return
        def Atk(self):
            Fists = 10
            Stick = 10
            Weopon = Fists
            Wand = Stick

            Level = 0
            Level_Up_Magic_Dmg = + 10 * Level
            Level_Up_Dmg = + 10 * Level
            Base_Player_Dmg = 10 + Weopon + Level_Up_Dmg
            Base_Magic_Dmg = 10 + Wand + Level
            print(Base_Magic_Dmg, Base_Player_Dmg)
            return

    Xp('self')
    print('')
    Atk('self')
    print('')
    Hp('self')

Player_Data_Vars('self')


Player_Data = Player_Data
```

My result:

> ```
> Traceback (most recent call last):
>   File "C:/Users/Luke/Desktop/Game Project Folder Python/Player Data.py", line 20, in Hp
>     Level = Xp('Level')
>   File "C:/Users/Luke/Desktop/Game Project Folder Python/Player Data.py", line 17, in Xp
>     Hp(self)
>   File "C:/Users/Luke/Desktop/Game Project Folder Python/Player Data.py", line 20, in Hp
>     Level = Xp('Level')
>   File "C:/Users/Luke/Desktop/Game Project Folder Python/Player Data.py", line 17, in Xp
>     Hp(self)
>   File "C:/Users/Luke/Desktop/Game Project Folder Python/Player Data.py", line 20, in Hp
>     Level = Xp('Level')
>   File "C:/Users/Luke/Desktop/Game Project Folder Python/Player Data.py", line 17, in Xp
>     Hp(self)
>   File "C:/Users/Luke/Desktop/Game Project Folder Python/Player Data.py", line 20, in Hp
>     Level = Xp('Level')
>   File "C:/Users/Luke/Desktop/Game Project Folder Python/Player Data.py", line 17, in Xp
>     Hp(self)
>   File "C:/Users/Luke/Desktop/Game Project Folder Python/Player Data.py", line 20, in Hp
>     Level = Xp('Level')
>   File "C:/Users/Luke/Desktop/Game Project Folder Python/Player Data.py", line 17, in Xp
>     Hp(self)
>   File "C:/Users/Luke/Desktop/Game Project Folder Python/Player Data.py", line 20, in Hp
>     Level = Xp('Level')
>   File "C:/Users/Luke/Desktop/Game Project Folder Python/Player Data.py", line 17, in Xp
>     Hp(self)
>   File "C:/Users/Luke/Desktop/Game Project Folder Python/Player Data.py", line 20, in Hp
>     Level = Xp('Level')
>   File "C:/Users/Luke/Desktop/Game Project Folder Python/Player Data.py", line 17, in Xp
> MemoryError: Stack overflow
> repeated:
> ```

Comment: Not only is this question inappropriate for Code Review, it's also inappropriate for Stack Overflow. It's a code dump and not properly turned into a Minimum Complete Verifiable Example.

Comment: @ThomasWard Yes, I couldn't see that originally because his errors were an unformatted blob of text.

Comment: @Hack-R Sorry mate, with my SO reputation I can only raise flags ;-)

Comment: Please read and follow the posting guidelines in the help documentation.  [Minimal, complete, verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) applies here.  We cannot effectively help you until you post your MCVE code and accurately describe the problem.
We should be able to paste your posted code into a text file and reproduce the problem you described.
Your posted code doesn't run.  I finally fixed your indentation errors and commented out the invalid system call.  However, without knowing what the routines are supposed to do, there's no way we can fix the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**ANALYSIS**

The basic problem is that you have a direct infinite recursion built into your class design.  **Xp** goes through some strange machinations to force a local variable from 0 to 10 and back to 0, which then causes a call to **Hp**.  **Hp** then immediately calls **Xp** with an unused argument, and you start all over.

**SYMPTOMS**

Your coding suggests that you have not yet learned to use character strings (such as 'self' vs **self**), local vs class variables (you seem to think that **Level**, for example, will magically appear outside the method where you define it), basic data flow (as with your manipulation of the variable **Xp**), class and method structure, and a variety of other language basics.

**WHERE TO GO FROM HERE**

Use incremental programming: start with a *tiny* task, such as setting a player's initial characteristics -- not a class yet, just one player as global variables.  Write those few lines of code.  Don't continue until they *work*: you've tested them reasonably well.

Then add another small capability.  Make that initialization a function.  Call it from the main program (far-left margin) and test it out.

Now write a trivial level-up function.  Then a trivial attack function.  Make sure you know how to call them from the main program.

This way, when you have a problem, you'll always know that it's likely to be in the last few lines you wrote.  Also, you'll be learning one or two things at a time, instead of a dozen.  Here, you overreached and tied yourself in knots in fewer than 40 lines.